# Same id for Single CSV in cakephp 3.0

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I want to generate same id for Single CSV entries in cakephp 3.0

Means
If first CSV has 3 entries, it should be like this

Q1-1, Q1-2, Q1-3.

If second CSV has 4 entries, It should be like this,

Q2-1,Q2-2,Q2-3,Q2-4.

```
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{
$host="localhost";
$db_user="root";
$db_password="";
$db="fmpstockcheck";
$conn=mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die (mysql_error());
$x=0;
$filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
    {   
      $file=fopen($filename,"r");
      while(($emapData=fgetcsv($file,10000,",")) !== FALSE)
      {
      $qno = $x + 1;
      $nqno = 'Q'.$qno'-'.$qno;
       $sql="INSERT INTO quotationmaster(QuoteNo,CustomerNo, QuoteValue,ExpiresOn, LocationID, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn, Status, Timestamp) VALUES(
        '$nqno','$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]','$emapData[4]','$emapData[5]','$emapData[6]','$emapData[7]','$emapData[8]',
          '$emapData[9]')";
         //echo $sql;
          mysql_query($sql);
          $sqlqry="INSERT INTO `quotedetails`(
          QuoteNo, LineCode, Category, PartNumber, LocationID, AvailableQty, OrderQty, OurDescription, ProfilePrice, CorePrice, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn, IsDeleted, Timestamp) VALUES(
          '$nqno','$emapData[10]','$emapData[11]','$emapData[12]','$emapData[3]','$emapData[13]','$emapData[14]','$emapData[15]','$emapData[16]',
          '$emapData[17]','$emapData[4]','$emapData[5]','$emapData[6]','$emapData[7]','$emapData[18]','$emapData[9]')";



          mysql_query($sqlqry); 
         $x++;  
      }

      echo "<div class='success'>Import successfull</div>";
    }
              fclose($file);


}
```

Now i am getting Q1-1,Q1-2, Q1-3,Q1-4.......continously. Any helps are appreciable

Comment: You need to store in database or at least in session the number of files already uploaded and you can increase the value of $x accordingly.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: I am not uploading csv into database. I want to change the Q1 values for each CSV. Thats what i am trying to do. I am not familiar with session.

Comment: Well, to me it seems that you are uploading the contents of the csv files to a database, but it is your call. There are plenty of tutorials out there on how to use session with php. Pls do some independent research and try to implement a solution yourself.

Comment: Nothing in the question looks like CakePHP.